# How can I install npm on termux

Tags: npm-install

I'm trying to install npm using the npm install command on android termux and I got errors is there a way to go about this

If there is way please help

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple:-
After installing termux open app and run command

```
apt update 
apt upgrade
```

After that simply write

```
pkg install nodejs-lts
```

Or
Write

```
npm
```

After writing `npm` termux will say "npm package is not installed , install by executing //code
And you are done run here are the two options ..
Hope it helps

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with recommendations.

Comment: This is better than `apt update && apt upgrade` since if for whatever reason `apt update` fails you can still do `apt upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

I think you could be a little more specific on the errors you got. Anyway I think you can install nodejs package on termux using `pkg install nodejs` which will install **node** and **npm** on your device. Then check the version using `npm -v`.

Comment: npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/Movies/kikisapp/kik/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' ->

Comment: npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

It is important: after install termux from store, open the console, and update/upgrade it to latest version. The checks in the following list are skippables.

```
// system update, there could be changes to the state of store version
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

//check linux version ( 2021.01.19. current:  apt/stable 2.1.15, Linux 4.4.23+)
termux-info

// Access Android and Chrome hardware features.
apt install termux-api

// install nodejs
apt install nodejs

//check npm version ( 2021.01.19. current:  6.14.10)
npm -v

// check node version (current: v14.15.4)
node -v
```

Answer (score -1):

**Install**

Make sure you've first installed the *termux-api* on your Android device from the *Play store.*

Then install the scripts with apt install *termux-api*.

*Finally get this node module:*

```
$ npm install --save termux

Example usage
const api = require('termux')

if (!api.hasTermux) process.exit(1)

api.vibrate()
   .duration(1000)
   .run()

api.clipboardGet()
   .run()
   .then(function (text) {
     // ...
   })
```

This is from my side if you still face any issue please feel free to ask.

Comment: I still got error when I run this npm install - - save termux